# Vite (react) project after building, dist folder/assets don't have any image

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages, vite

I create a react project by using vite. When i run command `npm run build` to build my project then dist folder is create but my images are neither showing in dist/assets nor in deploy page on github.[image: my folder structure image]

[image: my terminal image]

My previous projects build without any problen dist/assets/ folder.I have already added base in vite.config.js.

I think that my images are not including when i build my project.I want to build my project with images.Sorry, for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I were putting image source like this: 'src/images/image.png'.thats was reason why build command not adding image to dist folder. Correct way to give image source like this : './images/image.png'.

You can also give image src by import images.

```
import image from "./images/image.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the image an import, like so `import img1 from "./assests/img"`, instead of using an inline file path